# Finding which file defines extern value

Tags: matlab, makefile, raspberry-pi, gpgpu, matlab-compiler

I am using raspberry PI to run some assembler code on GPU.

It works like this: you assemble the code into binary file. Then you include it into a C code which pushes data into the GPU. This binary file is defined as

```
extern uint32_t arrayOfCode[];
```

However I can not find where is this code included(it is not in any other include files). 
The whole code can be found [here](https://github.com/jetpacapp/pi-gemm)

Upon running makefile it works. 
Where the problem comes is when I am trying to build it as [MEX function](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/matlab_external/standalone-example.html) in Matlab.

Matlab cannot find where is the assembler binary code defined. Thus I have a suspicion that it must be linked somehow in **Makefile** since that's the only difference in building it. 
Does anyone has an idea how to find where is this extern value defined ?

==EDIT 1==
I posted my one solution how to build this into a Matlab library.
But the question remains more or less the same. How this makefile

```
CXX=g++

ASMSRCS := gemm_float.asm
ASMOBJS := $(subst .asm,.do,$(ASMSRCS))

CPPSRCS := $(shell find . -name '*.cpp' -not -name '._*')
CPPOBJS := $(subst .cpp,.o,$(CPPSRCS))

CPPFLAGS=-Ofast -DTARGET_PI -march=armv6 \
-mfloat-abi=hard \
-ftree-vectorize \
-funroll-all-loops \
-mfpu=vfp \

%.cdat: %.asm helpers.asm
    m4 $< | qpu-asm -o $(basename $@).cdat -c g_$(basename $@)Code

%.do: %.cdat
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -x c -c $< -o $(basename $@).do  

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -fPIC -c $< -o $(basename $@).o

gemm: $(CPPOBJS) $(ASMOBJS)
    g++ -g -O3 -o gemm $(CPPOBJS) $(ASMOBJS) -lblas
```

Could include "gemm_float.asm" assembled code into the C array defined with the keyword extern. I read that these "%." rules in makefile are rules for dependencies. Okay, that would mean that "gemm" would build anew if I changed something in files that "gemm" depends on. Or I might not understand makefiles well enough.

Comment: That's a big code base. I suggest you prepare a [minimal complete example](http://www.sscce.org/); it will make our job much easier (and thereby increase the number of us who will try), and there is a good chance that you will discover the answer yourself in the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by separately building C code and assembler code. This is for anyone who cannot use an original makefile for some reason(mine was trying to build this into a mex Matlab library).

First, we build code.asm into binary file

```
m4 code.asm | ./qpu-asm -o code.bin
```

Now we have to adjust our C code in such a way that it loads .bin code in it's main function. I used a function from eman's [tutorial](http://rpiplayground.wordpress.com/2014/05/03/hacking-the-gpu-for-fun-and-profit-pt-1/) which simply reads the assembler code from a bin file and saves it into an array for later use.

```
int loadQPUCode(const char *fname, unsigned int* buffer, int len)
{
   FILE *in = fopen(fname, "r");
   if (!in) {
   fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open %s.\n", fname);
   return -1;
   }

   size_t items = fread(buffer, sizeof(unsigned int), len, in);
   fclose(in);
   return items * sizeof(unsigned int);
}
```

Then it is enough to call call this before using any gpu related function.

```
loadQPUCode("asmCode.bin",arrayOfCode,CONSTANT_RELATIVE_TO_ASMCODE);
```

With this adjusted C code and binary assembler code I was able to build Matlab library using matlab mex function.

```
mex main.cpp include1.cpp include2.cpp
```